# Print regex string found with grep

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

I have this crazy long command-turned-(bash)script that outputs a tiny table with and object and some other data relate to it. I want to single the name of the object out to use it as a variable to further run more commands.

It outputs something like this:

```
ID          PATH       NAME           VERSION             UPGRADE STATUS
vm-13034    /abc/def   somethingelse  vX.X.X-XXX-XXXXXXX  Up to date
```

The value I'm interested in is **ID**, which always is vm-#####. With an online tool I came up with the regex `^vm-\d{5,}$` (`,` bc the number is incrementing). So I figured `vosxls | grep -E ^vm-\d{5,}$` (vosxls is the script's name for the long command) would work but it returns nothing. I tried it with `-w`, `-e`, `grep -e "vm-\d{5,}" <(vosxls)` and a few more adding and remove the enclosing `^` & `$` characters when it would throw an error, enclosing the string in soft- and hard quotes or nothing at all, whatever would work.

Everything else that didn't error, returned nothing.

I read some examples with Perl and stuff similar to that but I stayed away and generally have stayed as basic as possible so I can run it in another system without issues. The most I've diverted from the most basic stuff (which are all I know anyway) was `egrep` which is I believe is the same as `grep -e` if I'm not mistaken.

How can the string be printed out? Is it because I'm already using a script it somehow affects how grep works? The script has no variables, it is merely a shorthand to avoid typing a lot of difficult to remember syntax+values.

Thanks.

Comment: `cut -f1 -d' '` maybe. Probably something else is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be as simple as

```
vosxls | grep -Eo "^vm-\d{5,}"
```

Specifying -o allows you to return whatever matches the regex only.

```
-o, --only-matching
    Prints only the matching part of the lines.
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like `vosxlx | sed -n 's/\(vm.*\ \)\(\/.*\)/\1/p'`?

Or maybe `vosxlx | awk '/vm/ {print $1}'`

Comment: Thanks, @taylor-g's worked out fine and the simplest but I've been meaning to learn about `sed` and `awk` for a while and I keep forgetting. I guess it's as good a time as any. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
foo | perl -ne 'print $1 if /^(vm-\d+)/'
```

Your version of grep might not have extended regex support:

```
$:/mnt/c/Users/sukuj$ cat /tmp/s.txt
ID          PATH       NAME           VERSION             UPGRADE STATUS
vm-13034    /abc/def   somethingelse  vX.X.X-XXX-XXXXXXX  Up to date
vm-23034    /abc/def   somethingelse  vX.X.X-XXX-XXXXXXX  Up to date

$:/mnt/c/Users/sukuj$ grep -oE 'vm-[0-9]+' /tmp/s.txt
vm-13034
vm-23034

$:/mnt/c/Users/sukuj$ grep -oE 'vm-[0-9]{5,}' /tmp/s.txt
vm-13034
vm-23034

$:/mnt/c/Users/sukuj$ grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 3.4
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others; see
<https://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
suku@DESKTOP-GID8MQV:/mnt/c/Users/sukuj$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `\d` with the `-E` option of grep to denote a digit. `-P`, respectively `-Po`, will work. But if you already know that you need the **first** field of the **last** line of the output, you don't need grep. A

```
vosxlx | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

would do as well.